# PHP how to connect to FTP using Implicit FTP over TLS

Tags: php, curl, ftp

Apparently the native FTP functionality of FTP does not support implicit FTP over TLS

I tried this using Curl but doesn't work:

```
$ftp_server = 'data.example.com/file.csv'; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ftp_server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,'abcde'.':'.'123456');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_TRY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
$file = fopen('local_file.csv', "w+");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$error_no = curl_errno($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

If I try without a file name in the URL I appear to reach the server as I get an IIS welcome page. If I try with the file, I get a 404 error. I know the file is accurate as I can access via Filezilla.

Thank you

Comment: __`ftps://`__ `data.example.com/file.csv`

Comment: Perfect! Simple enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL should include the scheme, e.g.:

```
$ftp_server = 'ftps://data.example.com/file.csv';
```

From [CURLOPT_URL explained](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_URL.html):

> If the given URL is missing a scheme name (such as "http://" or "ftp://" etc) then libcurl will make a guess based on the host. If the outermost sub-domain name matches DICT, FTP, IMAP, LDAP, POP3 or SMTP then that protocol will be used, otherwise HTTP will be used.

You're hitting the IIS welcome page and 404 errors because you're making an http request rather than connecting via ftps.

Comment: Thanks. hanshenrik did provide the same answer. I would give him the credit but he didn't provide it as an answer.

Comment: @user2029890 ^^ its fine, just mark this as accepted. thanks for being so considerate, though. (ps, i suggest NOT letting curl guess, as a general rule, be explicit, that avoids surprises)